# Core Data pulling changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Ok, here's the problem: I use `managedObjectContext` hierarchy. I have a root `managedObjectContext` that is singleton so I can share same context and in the same time I can have child context for separating saving.

```
_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

_managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
```

And this is how I create child `managedObjectContext` which I have one for each `viewController`

```
NSManagedObjectContext* childContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
childContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
childContext.parentContext = _managedObjectContext;
```

For everyone who thinks that it's enough to save just child `managedObjectContext`, save works only one ancestor up, you have to do it until parent is `nil`. I have just parent and child so this is my code for saving data to store

```
- (void)saveChildContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)childContext
{
    [childContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError* error;
        [childContext save:&error];

        [_managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            NSError* parentError;
           [_managedObjectContext save:&parentError];
        }];
    }];
}
```

I have a `viewController` that fetches data for a `tableView`.

```
arrObjects = [dbClient getEntitiesOfType:@"Object" predicate:@"%K == nil || %K.length < 1" predicateArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"someRelationship.property", @"someRelationship.otherProperty", nil] childContext:childContext];
```

And this is behind:

```
- (NSArray*)getEntitiesOfType:(NSString *)entityType predicate:(NSString*)predicateString predicateArray:(NSArray*)predicateArray childContext(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;

    if (context != nil)
        managedObjectContext = context;
    else
        managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    if (managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        NSEntityDescription* entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityType inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

        NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString argumentArray:predicateArray];

        NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        request.entity = entityDescription;
        request.predicate = predicate;

        NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        return [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    }
    else
        return nil;
}
```

When going to details of one of fetched results, I make changes, save context, which propagates changes to  parent and then to store. I pass the object and in details I work with object's `managedObjectContext`. After saving data to store, I pop my `viewController` and everything is fine.

If I choose to do something with that object on another `viewController`, I save context because I made some changes, pass `objectId`, I fetch that object with another `managedObjectContext`, but that has same parent, make changes and save it to parent and then to store. Everything is stored nicely. Oh, here I use `NSNotification` because `viewControllers` don't know about the other's existence.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:currentTrip.objectID, @"ObjectId", nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"tripRecording" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

**The problem** is that when I get to first `viewController` (`tableViewController`), I fetch data on `viewWillAppear`, and I don't get changes. On the other hand, if I press segment on same view, fetch another data and then get back to first segment, pressing it and fetching first set of data again, I get correct answers. That means that data got stored correctly, no matter which context I used.

My questions are:

1. How is it possible that `managedObjectContext` doesn't see changes unless I change `fetchRequest` and then fetch again first request?
2. Is `reset` on `managedObjectContext` the only way to get correct data?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Show us your code. 2. Remember to format your questions to make them look better and more readable.

Comment: You should be creating your child context with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` not `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`. That's the first thing I see. This is a rather dense question so I want to look more before providing a full answer.

Comment: @random But I want to be it on main thread...

Comment: @StanleyKubrick just because it's `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` doesn't mean that it's not on the main thread. You should only have one `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`, this is your *master* context. You create child context of `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` that reference back to your single `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`

Comment: @random OK, I'll give it a try. I thought that it was a matter of implementation.

Comment: @random Nothing changed. When I fetched object by `objectId` there were no changes made by other `managedObjectContext`. It's like I have to stores. But I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my setup using two different `NSManagedObjectContext`:

Creating my master `NSManagedObjectContext`, I never directly work off this context:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)masterManagedObjectContext {
    if (_masterManagedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _masterManagedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _masterManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_masterManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            [_masterManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        }];

    }
    return _masterManagedObjectContext;
}
```

Creating a new `NSManagedObjectContext` on the fly:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)newManagedObjectContext {

    NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = nil;

    NSManagedObjectContext *masterContext = [self masterManagedObjectContext];

    if (masterContext != nil) {

        newContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

        [newContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            [newContext setParentContext:masterContext];

            NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
            [notificationCenter addObserver:self
                                   selector:@selector(backgroundDidSaveNotification:)
                                       name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                     object:newContext];
        }];
    }

    return newContext;
}
```

Method to listen for when the new `NSManagedObjectContext` saves so it can merge into master:

```
- (void)backgroundDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification*)notificaton {
    [self.masterManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notificaton];
    [self saveMasterContext];
}
```

For clarity my `saveMasterContext`:

```
- (void)saveMasterContext {
    [self.masterManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        BOOL saved = [self.masterManagedObjectContext save:&error];
        if (!saved) {
            // do some real error handling
            NSLog(@"Could not save master context due to %@", error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try with `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`. But if children save changes to parent, isn't that enough for them to see other changes? Although I use same parent context, it appears I have two of them.

Comment: Child context do not automatically get pushed changes from the parent context. So if one child saves and pushes to parent, the other children won't know it unless you explicitly notify them.

Comment: Sorry, I used wrong words. Of course, sibling has to pull data from parent, but I don't see it, unless I reset context. Also, I see changes when fetch something else and then what I wanted in first place. If I just fetch what I want, I don't see changes.

Comment: OK, I accepted your answer. Your solution as well as mine are good. The problem was, and the article says it nicely, that you have to either reset (my solution) `managedObjectContext` or create new one if you want merged changes to be seen in sibling context. Thanks again, random.